# Using jQuery to display input TITLE as VALUE (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, watermark, jsfiddle

I am trying to come up with a simple jquery input watermark function. Basically, if the input field has no value, display it's title.

I have come up with the jquery necessary to assign the input's value as it's title, but it does not display on the page as if it was a value that was hand-coded into the form.

How can I get this to display the value when the page loads in the input field for the user to see?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mQ3sX/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".wmk").each(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      var title = $(this).attr("title");

      if (value == '') {
        value = title;
      }

      $(".result").text(value);
      // You can see I can get something else to display the value, but it does 
      // not display in the actual input field.            
    });

});
```

Comment: Even when there's a link to the fiddle, you should paste the relevant code into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below line of code. You need to specify the input element, and update its value. Since your input field has a class called '.wmk', I am using the below code. You can use "id" and use "#" instead of ".". Read more about selectors at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$(".wmk").val(value);
```

Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bhatlx/mQ3sX/9/

Update: since you are using 'each' on '.wmk', you can use

```
 $(this).val(value)
```

Comment: I updated the code to use '$(this)' since you are looping over input elements with class '.wmk'

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing your own, have you considered using a ready-bake version?  It's not exactly what you asked for, but these have additional functionality you might like (for instance, behaving like a normal placeholder that auto-hides the placeholder when you start typing).

http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder

Comment: Seems like every one I've found say they don't work in all browsers.

Comment: Usually they say that the HTML5 placeholder attribute only works in some browsers.  The first link carries this caveat, but the jQuery solution works in all browsers.

Comment: Practically the only browser-specific jQuery plugins carry that designation because they are enabling functionality a browser doesn't have, not because they don't work in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".wmk").each(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var title = $(this).attr("title");

    if (value == '') {
        $(this).val(title);
    }

    $(".result").text(value);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/mQ3sX/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".wmk").each (function () {
        if (this.value == '') this.value = this.title;
    });

    $(".wmk").focus(
        function () {
            if (this.value == this.title) this.value = '';
        }
    ).blur(
        function () {
            if (this.value == '') this.value = this.title;
        }
    );

}); // end doc ready
```